# Outlook 2016 'NOT READ' bug

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

in my company the accounting department uses outlook 2016.
there are 3 employees who share one imap account.
each outlook logs into the same account and they receive and send on that same account. there are also shared folders from other department's account, but only with viewing permissions. the underlying mailserver is postfix & dovecot.

here comes the problem: anytime their outlooks resync with server they send out 'NOT READ' notifications. lots of them.

i have checked their configs and each outlook is configured to NOT send any read receipts.

i googled and found old posts on ms forums etc about that bug, but nowhere a solution.

could anyone please give me a hint?

maybe there is some registry key i could modify.
all ms office are up to date...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue only happen to this IMAP account?

Please check the options mentioned in [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-and-request-read-receipts-and-delivery-notifications-a34bf70a-4c2c-4461-b2a1-12e4a7a92141) to see if you’ve selected “Request a read receipt for this message”.

Please also send an email directly on the web mail and then see if you still receive Read Receipt. This helps determine whether it lies on server side or client side.

Besides, we can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

What’s the detailed version of Outlook 2016? I haven’t found official articles regarding this “bug”. You may install newest updates to see if it helps.